# When using Material-UI's tab component, how do I customize the style for a selected tab?

Tags: reactjs, tabs, material-ui

I'm tryin got use the Material-ui Tab component in my React app -- https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/.  I have set up my Tab bar like so

```
  <AppBar position="static">
    <Tabs
      classes={classes}
      value={value}
      variant="fullWidth"
      centered
      onChange={handleChange}
      aria-label="volunteer dashboard tabs"
    >
      <Tab label={proposedLabel} {...a11yProps(2)} />
      <Tab label={planningLabel} {...a11yProps(1)} />
      <Tab label={inProgressLabel} {...a11yProps(0)} />
      <Tab label={completedLabel} {...a11yProps(3)} />
    </Tabs>
  </AppBar>
```

My question is, how do I customize the style of the tab when it is selected?  The documentation lists the "indicator" class, so I use these styles

```
  root2: {
    width: "100%",
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
  root3: {
    paddingRight: theme.spacing(1),
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: "100%",
  },
  viewButtons: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  indicator: {
    border: 0,
    borderBottom: "2px solid",
    "&:hover": {
      border: 0,
      borderBottom: "2px solid",
    },
  }
```

However, this class isn't taking effect.  What's the proper class to use in order to properly style a selected tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **active** indicator is actually part of the [tab](https://material-ui.com/api/tab/) component, and not the tabs one. If you check inside you will see there a `selected` prop (which will be `.Mui-selected`).

You should use the createMuiTheme with the MuiThemeProvider to style that:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTab: {
      root: {
        "&.Mui-selected": {
          background: "red"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-theme-style-selected-tab-pe03k?file=/demo.js

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this.  If you're interested in a follow-up, I wasn't able to figure out from teh docs how to override the selected color of the tab -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61394435/how-do-i-override-material-uis-tab-selection-color

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to change the styles of the indicator (border Bottom of the tab),
i had faced the same issue, but had found a workaround for this, this solution a bit of a hack but it works, you need to set the indicator Background to transparent and apply the styles to its inner div as shown below,

```
indicator: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    '& > div': {
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
        },
    },
},
```

hover only works when you hover on the indicator,
if you want to change indicator color when you hover on your tab, 
you need to apply the styles to the root.