# How do I override material-ui's tab selection color?

Tags: reactjs, tabs, material-ui

I'm building a React 16.13.0 application with the materialui-tabs theme, https://material-ui.com/api/tab/.  I have created these styles in my component ...

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTab: {
      root: {
        "&.MuiTab-root": {
          backgroundColor: "black",
          border: 0,
          borderBottom: "2px solid",
          "&:hover": {
            border: 0,
            borderBottom: "2px solid",
          },
        },
        "&.Mui-selected": {
          backgroundColor: "none",
          borderBottom: "2px solid #373985",
          borderColor: "#373985",
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    flexGrow: 1,
    color: "#3739B5",
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },
  viewButtons: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}));
```

These are applied to

```
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <AppBar position="static">
    <Tabs
      classes={classes}
      value={value}
      variant="fullWidth"
      centered
      onChange={handleChange}
      aria-label="volunteer dashboard tabs"
    >
      <Tab label={proposedLabel} {...a11yProps(2)} />
      <Tab label={planningLabel} {...a11yProps(1)} />
      <Tab label={inProgressLabel} {...a11yProps(0)} />
      <Tab label={completedLabel} {...a11yProps(3)} />
    </Tabs>
  </AppBar>
  </ThemeProvider>
```

I'm trying to change the background color of the selected tab.  Based on devtools, inspection, the class is listed as

```
.PrivateTabIndicator-colorSecondary-267 {
             background-color: #f50057;
}

.PrivateTabIndicator-root-265 {
            width: 100%;
             bottom: 0;
             height: 2px;
             position: absolute;
             transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
}
```

However, despite the fact I have listed that in my theme, the color appears as red, despite what I specified in my style

[image]

How can I override the border color of the selected tab?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Can you try this solution working for me. I assume that you want to override the bottom border indicator color.

```
    <Tabs value={0} TabIndicatorProps={{ style: { background: "#hex-color" } }}>
         <Tab className={clasess.tab} label="Home" />
         <Tab className={clasess.tab} label="Services" />
    </Tabs>
```

Answer (score 8):

Starting from MUI v5, it can be easily done in using the `createTheme()]`API as shown [here](https://mui.com/customization/theming/#createtheme-options-args-theme).

You need to override the styles using something like this:

```
  let theme = useTheme();

  theme = createTheme(theme, {
    components: {
      MuiTab: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root:{
            "&.Mui-selected": {
              backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
              color: theme.palette.secondary.contrastText,
              borderRadius: "25px"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

This theme can be passed to a `<ThemeProvider />` component which would wrap the section where the tabs are present.

*Note*:

1. `useTheme()`, `createTheme()` and `<ThemeProvider />` all need to be imported from `@mui/material/styles` and not from `@emotion/react`.
2. Starting from v5, `@mui/lab` provides `<TabContext />`, `<TabList />`, and `<TabPanel />` components which the [docs](https://mui.com/components/tabs/) recommend using though you can still use the old components of `<Tabs />`.

Answer (score 7):

You can now use the TabIndicatorProps to style the active indicator with the current version of MUI (4.10.02). Docs available [here](https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/).

There are 2 ways to do this:

**METHOD 1: *using style: {}***

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Tabs, Tab, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const TabsIndicator = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
       <Tabs
         value={value}
         onChange={handleChange}
         TabIndicatorProps={{
           style: { background: "cyan", height: "10px", top: "35px" }
         }}
       >
         <Tab label="TEST1" value={0} />
         <Tab label="TEST2" value={1} />
         <Tab label="TEST3" value={2} />
         <Tab label="TEST4" value={3} />
       </Tabs>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default TabsIndicator;
```

**Method 2: *using className: {classes}***

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Tabs, Tab, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  indicator: {
    backgroundColor: "green",
    height: "10px",
    top: "45px"
  }
}));

const TabsIndicator = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          TabIndicatorProps={{ className: classes.indicator }}
        >
          <Tab label="TEST1" value={0} />
          <Tab label="TEST2" value={1} />
          <Tab label="TEST3" value={2} />
          <Tab label="TEST4" value={3} />
        </Tabs>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default TabsIndicator;
```

You can also check out my [sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-tabs-sbwch?file=/src/pages/sections/Tabs01indicator.js:0-2178). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this !

```
indicator: {
    backgroundColor : 'your favorite color',
},


<Tabs classes={{ indicator: classes.indicator }}>
   <Tab>....
</Tabs>
```